# loop through char list to import xlsx files SAS

Tags: sas

Hi i have a simple question yet all the responses I've found are extremely complicated, I have a list of file names that i want to refer to in my macro in order to import all the files here is where I am

```
 %let y20 = Jan20 Feb20;  
 %macro boucle_doCC(in);
    
    proc import datafile ="&rep.\&in..xlsx"
                out=&in
                dbms=xlsx replace; 
                getnames=yes;
    run;
    %end;
    %mend boucle_doCC;
```

I know i need a do loop before the proc import but i dont know how to do it can you help please ?

Comment: This has been answered here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44288284/sas-loop-through-list-of-macro-variable/44289143#44289143

Answer (score 0):

```
data files;
   input file $;
   datalines;
Jan20
Feb20
;

%macro boucle_doCC(in=,rep=/*repository here*/);
    proc import datafile ="&rep.\&in..xlsx"
    out=&in
    dbms=xlsx 
    replace; 
    getnames=yes;
run;
%mend boucle_doCC; 

data _null_;
    set files;
    call symputx('file',file);
    call execute('%boucle_doCC(in='||file||');');
run;
```