# SAS LOOP MACRO LIST

Tags: sas

Do you know how can I iterate on a list using SAS and a MACRO ?

```
%LET table           = item1 item2;/*List of all input*/

/*I try to iterate on the list using a macro*/

%MACRO Main_Extract ;
    array orig[*] &table; 
    do i=1 to dim(orig);
    %put orig[i];
    end; 
%MEND;

%Main_Extract;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do overall. This looks like a mix of data step and macro code that probably isn't going to do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple iteration through array with proc sql in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667379/simple-iteration-through-array-with-proc-sql-in-sas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If table, the list of items, is of variable names for an array, then you do not need a macro.  Just use plain data step code and use the macro variable to list the array elements.

```
array orig &table;
do I = 1 to dim(orig);
  put orig[I]=
end;
```

When a macro variable contains a space separated list of items, the use of such inside of a macro is usually done by parsing out each item using `%scan` inside a `%do` loop.  An example of when this is useful would be generating a series of select clauses for a Proc SQL statement.

One time use of parsing out each item

```
%macro special_sauce (items=);
  %local i item;
  %let i = 1;
  %do %while (%length(%scan(&items,&i)));
    %let item = %scan(&items,&i);

    %put NOTE: code generated for &=item;

    /* ... emit some SAS code or code-snippet involving &item ... */
    &item._squared = &item ** 2;  /* emit data step source statement that presumes item is a variable name that is being squared */

    %let i = %eval(&i+1);
  %end;
%mend;

options mprint;

data want;
  set sashelp.class;
  %special_sauce(items=age height)
run;
```

If the list of items is needed to be used more than once it is also helpful to store the individual items in local macro variables for easy re-use.

List of items used more than once, parse once and put items in a 'macro-array'.  There is really no such thing as a macro-array, simply a convention of numerically suffixed symbol names that can be iterated over.

```
%macro special_sauce2 (items=);
  %local i item itemCount;
  %let i = 1;
  %do %while (%length(%scan(&items,&i)));
    %let item = %scan(&items,&i);

    %let itemCount = &i;  /* track number of items parsed */ 
    %local item&i;        /* local macro variable name with numeric suffix, sometimes called a macro array */
    %let item&i = &item;  /* save the extracted item */

    %let i = %eval(&i+1);
  %end;

  /* use the items in the 'macro-array' */
  %do i = 1 %to &itemCount;
    %put NOTE: value of macro variable item&i is &&item&i;
    &&item&i.._2 = &&item&i ** 2;
  %end;

  /* use the items in the 'macro-array' */
  %do i = 1 %to &itemCount;
    %put NOTE: Hi again, value of macro variable item&i is &&item&i;
    &&item&i.._3 = &&item&i ** 3;
  %end;
%mend;

options mprint;

data want;
  set sashelp.class;
  %special_sauce2(items=age height)
run;
```

Good rule of thumb, don't macro if you don't have to.